# Who is the founder of the subsite Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I know that Stack Overflow (and subsequently Stack Exchange) was founded by Jeff Atwood and co-founded by Joel Spolsky.

But regarding Ask Ubuntu, who took the decision to start a subsite around Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11):

The [Ubuntu Area 51 Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu) was originally started by this lovely fella:

[image]

Comment: @Feucniger +1 how do I get to 15 rep? I want to upvote your answer.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Well, you'll have to earn the reputation on [the main site](http://askubuntu.com). Post some valuable content, once people upvote you, you will receive [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help-center/reputation).

Comment: @Feucjigner Can you suggest me a topic? Is there an alternative if you have nothing to offer to the community and just want to show your appreciation to someone?

Comment: @JeffAtwood This being a very content-focused site, there isn't much else you can do. Please do refer to the [/help-center](http://askubuntu.com/help-center) on this.

Comment: @Feihcninger mmm ok :) maybe reposting content from some forum can help :)

Comment: @JeffAtwood While you may not be able to upvote, you *should* be able to accept the answer.  Just click the grey arrow below the voting arrows so that it turns green(the accept counts for more than the upvote, upvote=+10, accept=+15, you could still upvote when you get the rep)